# VBA Excel Validation From Named Range Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I have a macro that adds validations on a change event. In name manager, I had a table that was "Table1" that I changed to "tblBrand". This line of code is supposed to create a list from that table, but it's throwing error 1004.

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertInformation, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=tblBrand"
```

Weirdly, I had used the name box previously, and named this table "shtblBrand" before, and this worked fine. But in name manager, I basically had each table named twice. So this table was in name manager as Table1 and shtblBrand. So to be efficient, I deleted the shtblBrand, and just renamed Table1 to tblBrand. That's when it stopped working and threw the error 1004.

Comment: Could you please share more of the code? What is the Object that `.Add` is called on?

Comment: What's happening when try `Range("tblBrand").select`? Does it selecting the range you need to process?

Comment: Range("tblBrand").select selects the range without the header.

Comment: This is the full code for that validation
.With shPD.Cells(tr, Range("pdBrand").Column).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertInformation, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=tblBrand"
    End With

Comment: This only proves that the range used in `Formula` is correct (the table `DataBodyRange`). What about `Range("pdBrand")`?

Comment: Range("pdBrand") also works fine.

Comment: If I put that, it doesn't pull in the table, it just makes my validation list one choice of tblBrand.

Comment: So, how do you want using the data from `tblBrand` `DataBodyRange`? Are you sure that you didn't use **only** one column of the respective range? Do you want having **all the values from the respective range**, in the validation list?

Comment: tblBrand, is a table with one column, and 132 rows. I want my validation list to be that table with the 132 choices.

Comment: Please try `Formula1:=Join(Application.Transpose(Range("tblBrand").value),",")` This will make a comma separated list...

Comment: One thing I just found as you were writing your last comment, in Name Manager, there are table defaults that have a gray table icon, which is what I renamed. There's also named ranges I named via the Name Box, which have blue icons. If in my code, I have Formula1="=tblBrand" and that is referencing a table name with a gray icon, it does not work. But if it's referencing a table with a blue icon, it works properly. I don't understand why tables can have two separate names with two separate icons in name manager, but that seems to be my underlying issue. So I'll have to rename them all.

Comment: But you said that `Range("tblBrand").select` selected the correct named range. So, VBA/Excel recognizes it as it is... If so, did you try the above (last) suggestion). It will force the range value to be transformed firstly in a 1D array, then to join it with comma (`","`) separator. Or you can try `Formula1:=Range("tblBrand")`. If not, we came back to the initial question...

Comment: By renaming the gray icon tables back to their defaults, Table1, Table2, and so on, and then using the name box to name them with the names I want such as tblBrand, which gives it a blue icon in Name Manager, I can then reference them as I was before, Formula1="=tblBrand" and it works properly. My issue was the difference between the blue and gray icons in Name Manager. I'm sure your solution works, I was just able to fix it doing this as well, and it's less code, although I'm back to having one table named twice in Name manager, one with gray icon, one with blue.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You should not put an `=` sign into the formula, the corrected code is:</strike> Actually, you should.

```
With shPD.Cells(tr, Range("pdBrand").Column).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertInformation, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="tblBrand"
End With
```

OK, I've experimented further. Somehow Tables are not normal Names. If you look at them in the Names window, they have a different icon, and they are not enumerated in `ThisWorkbook.Names`. And as it turned out, they are not allowed in this Formula1.

You should either create a new name with the same range, or create a new name, e.g. `tblBrandIndirect` that refers to the table `=tblBrand` (possible via VBA but easier through Names window), and use that name in `Formula1`:

```
With shPD.Cells(tr, Range("pdBrand").Column).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertInformation, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="tblBrandIndirect"
End With
```

This way you can use it both as a table and as a normal name, and do not need to update its address.

Comment: Oh, wait. I tried and I no longer get the error, but it's just making that name "tblBrand" my only choice in the validation list. It's not bring in the table. list of 132 items that name represents